# Check if TextArea/TextBox contains a certain String

Tags: javascript

Given textarea is a textarea element with id 'textareabox', how can I check if it contains a string within it?

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textareabox');

var word = something;

if (!textarea.contains(word))
{
textarea.value += word;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.value`, as:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textareabox');

var word = 'something';

var textValue=textarea.value;  //-> don't use .innerHTML since there is no HTML in a textarea element

if (textValue.indexOf(word)!=-1)
{
  alert('found')
}
```

Comment: Should you not use `.value` for text areas considering they are input elements?

Comment: Since it is a form tag, `value` is the proper way to do this.

Comment: there's no html inside a textarea

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt yes but that doesn't mean that using `innerHTML` is correct.

Comment: @pattmorter you are right, I was commenting on thomas's comment, that there is no html inside a textarea, I think he means innerHTML is not valid.

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt, it's not good practice to use `.innerHTML`. It doesn't assign well. http://www.coderanch.com/t/461237/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/InnerHTML-working-textarea

Comment: @JonathanM OK...thanks for the edit. and thanks for the link. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textareabox').value;

if (texarea.match(word) != null) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

A better regex than what I did but I don't know regex all that well (forgive me regex ignorance).

Comment: regex is overkill. `indexOf` will suffice

Comment: Good call. `indexOf` is easier and faster.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
background-color: red;


}
```

```html
<html>
<h1>#mywebsite</h1>
<body>1+1=2?(yes <strong>or</strong> no)</body>
<input type="text" id="text" placeholder="text here"></input>
<button type="button" id="u" onclick="run()">submit</button>
<script type="text/javascript">


var a = 1;
function run() {
if (document.getElementById("text").value.includes("yes")) {
alert("correct!");
/*if the textbox includes "yes" it will say you got it right; basically whatever the input your user puts into the textbox it will test if the users sentence contains "yes" it alerts "correct!" into html if its wrong well it alerts "Try again!" the thing is, no matter what, if yes is in the sentance it will still say its correct.*/
/*if the snippet will not work use a different website to put code on */
document.body.innerHTML += "<li>attempt #" + a + ": correct";
a++
}
 
else {

alert("try again!")
document.body.innerHTML += "<li>attempt #" + a + ": try again";
a++
}



}
</script>
```

Comment: Would add more explanation?