# How to add value of checked checkbox and select option to textarea using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want jQuery to auto add values of selected checkbox and value of selected option (drop down list) to a text area. Here is what I have done so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class=" wpcf7-list-item" id="voucher_150">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-680" value="150" id="Product50" onclick="enableQuantity('Product50','QuantityProd5');"">
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label 150guts">150€ Voucher x </span>
        <select name="form[QuantityProd5][]" id="QuantityProd5" onchange="calculateTotal();" class="rsform-select-box">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
        <span>&nbsp;Stück</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class=" wpcf7-list-item" id="voucher_200">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-680" value="200" id="Product60" onclick="enableQuantity('Product60','QuantityProd6');"">
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label 150guts">200€ Voucher x </span>
        <select name="form[QuantityProd6][]" id="QuantityProd6" onchange="calculateTotal();" class="rsform-select-box">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
        <span>&nbsp;Stück</span>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="t_area">
    <textarea id="get_checked"></textarea>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#voucher_150 :checkbox, #voucher_200 :checkbox").change(function() {   
var text = $("#voucher_150 :checked, #voucher_200 :checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(" ");
$("#get_checked").val(text);
});
```

FIDDLE: 
http://jsfiddle.net/8cfqkt4p/

Also, i dont understand why it ads 1,1 after checkbox value? So, in the result I imagine it ti look this way:

€150 - Voucher x 2 pieces

€200 - voucher x 1 pieces

Comment: *«i dont understand why it ads 1»* : You are using `:checked` in your selector... So it also gets the value of the `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

By selecting both checkbox it will return value of them. To fix it easily you should call onchange for everyone

```
$("#voucher_150 :checkbox").change(function() {   
    var text = $("#voucher_150 :checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(" ");
    $("#get_checked").val(text);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I continued working on my Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/8cfqkt4p/1/ but now i have a new problem. How can I make the value to disappear if one of checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: You can check textarea value and if it has a $150 Voucher x so you can remove it . see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167909/check-if-textarea-textbox-contains-a-certain-string

Answer (score 0):

> I dont understand why it ads 1

You are using `:checked` in your selector... So it also gets the value of the `<select>`.

Since you wish to have the `span` text intead of the checkbox value... I would use an `.each()` loop instead of `.map()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Event handler for checkboxes AND selects
  $("[type='checkbox'], select").on("change", function() {
    
    // Empty string
    var text = "";

    // For each checked checkbox
    $("[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
    
      // Get the span text
      text += $(this).siblings("span").first().text();
      
      // Get the select value
      text += $(this).siblings("select").val();
      
      // Line return
      text += "\n";
    });

    // Set the textarea value
    $("#get_checked").val(text);
  });

});
```

```css
textarea{
  width: 16em;
  height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="wpcf7-list-item" id="voucher_150">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-680" value="150" id="Product50">
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label 150guts">150€ Voucher x </span>
    <select name="form[QuantityProd5][]" id="QuantityProd5" class="rsform-select-box ">
      <option value="1 ">1</option>
      <option value="2 ">2</option>
      <option value="3 ">3</option>
      <option value="4 ">4</option>
      <option value="5 ">5</option>
      <option value="6 ">6</option>
      <option value="7 ">7</option>
      <option value="8 ">8</option>
      <option value="9 ">9</option>
      <option value="10 ">10</option>
    </select>
    <span>&nbsp;Stück</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
  <div class="wpcf7-list-item" id="voucher_200">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-680" value="200" id="Product60">
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label 150guts ">200€ Voucher x </span>
    <select name="form[QuantityProd6][]" id="QuantityProd6" class="rsform-select-box ">
      <option value="1 ">1</option>
      <option value="2 ">2</option>
      <option value="3 ">3</option>
      <option value="4 ">4</option>
      <option value="5 ">5</option>
      <option value="6 ">6</option>
      <option value="7 ">7</option>
      <option value="8 ">8</option>
      <option value="9 ">9</option>
      <option value="10 ">10</option>
    </select>
    <span>&nbsp;Stück</span>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="t_area">
  <textarea id="get_checked"></textarea>
</div>
```

Also... Be careful with the extra spaces in the markup attributes. `id="get_checked "` is different from `id="get_checked"` because the space is not ignored.